# How to achieve event compression in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, compression

In my application i'm getting series of Windows events and i want to compress them and process unique events in c++.

For example: Event W1, W2, W3, W4 ...., Event E1, E2... etc.,
If I'm getting only W1 series in timeframe I want to process only one event by compressing remaining events of same series.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <process.h>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <future>
#include <fstream> 

static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT1 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT1";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT2 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT2";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT3 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT3";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT4 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT4";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT5 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT5";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT6 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT6";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT7 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT7";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT8 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT8";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT9 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT9";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT10 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT10";
static const char* WFEVENTNAME_EVENT11 = "Global\\WFEVENTNAME_EVENT11";
std::ofstream outfile;
typedef std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockMutex;
typedef std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock;

class Handler1
{
public:
    bool ProcessMessage(std::string messageName)
    {
        printf("Processed Handler1\n");
        return true;
    }
};

class Handler2
{
public:
    bool ProcessMessage(std::string messageName)
    {
        printf("Processed Handler2\n");
        return true;
    }
};

class Handler3
{
public:
    bool ProcessMessage(std::string messageName)
    {
        printf("Processed Handler3\n");
        return true;
    }
};

class Handler4
{
public:
    bool ProcessMessage(std::string messageName)
    {
        printf("Processed Handler4\n");
        return true;
    }
};

class Handler5
{
public:
    bool ProcessMessage(std::string messageName)
    {
        printf("Processed Handler5\n");
        return true;
    }
};

class Handler6
{
public:
    bool ProcessMessage(std::string messageName)
    {
        printf("Processed Handler6\n");
        return true;
    }
};

unsigned _stdcall threadFuncToCollectSenderEvents(void* senderObject);
unsigned _stdcall threadFuncToProcessSenderEvents(void* senderObject);

class MessagingEventsNotifier
{
public:
    MessagingEventsNotifier()
    {
        _beginthreadex(0, 0, threadFuncToCollectSenderEvents, this, 0, 0);
        _beginthreadex(0, 0, threadFuncToProcessSenderEvents, this, 0, 0);
    }

    std::list<std::string> mySenderEvents;
    std::mutex myMutex;
    /// To notify to process the collected event
    std::condition_variable myConsumer;

    Handler1* myConnectionHandler;

    Handler2* myHandler2;

    Handler3* myLandmarkWorkflowHandler;

    Handler4* myHandler4;

    Handler5* myHandler5;

    Handler6* myHandler6;

    std::vector<HANDLE> myThreadHandles;
};

unsigned _stdcall threadFuncToCollectSenderEvents(void* senderObject)
{
    MessagingEventsNotifier *senderEventObject = static_cast<MessagingEventsNotifier*>(senderObject);

    while (true)
    {
        HANDLE hEvents[8];
        hEvents[0] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT3);
        hEvents[1] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT9);
        hEvents[2] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT5);
        hEvents[3] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT6);
        hEvents[4] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT1);
        hEvents[5] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT7);
        hEvents[6] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT2);
        hEvents[7] = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT10);

        DWORD result = WaitForMultipleObjects(8, hEvents, false, INFINITE);

        lockMutex l(senderEventObject->myMutex);        
        if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 0)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT3);
        }
        else if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 1)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT9);
        }
        else if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 2)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT5);
        }
        else if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 3)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT6);
        }
        else if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 4)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT1);
        }
        else if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 5)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT7);
        }
        else if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 6)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT2);
        }
        else if ((result - WAIT_OBJECT_0) == 7)
        {
            senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.push_back(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT10);
        }

        senderEventObject->myConsumer.notify_one();
    }

    return true;
}

unsigned _stdcall threadFuncToProcessSenderEvents(void* senderObject)
{
    MessagingEventsNotifier *senderEventObject = static_cast<MessagingEventsNotifier*>(senderObject);
    ulock unlockMutex(senderEventObject->myMutex);

    while (true)
    {
        senderEventObject->myConsumer.wait(unlockMutex);

        if (senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.size() <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.unique();

        for (std::list<std::string>::iterator it = senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.begin();
            it != senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.end(); ++it)
        {
            i++;
            std::string str = "Count = " + std::to_string(i) + "\n";
            outfile.write(str.c_str(), str.size());
            outfile.flush();

            printf("Processed Events Count: %d\n", i);

            std::string eventName = *it;
            if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT3)
            {
                senderEventObject->myLandmarkWorkflowHandler->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT3);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            else if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT9)
            {
                senderEventObject->myHandler2->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT9);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            else if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT5)
            {
                senderEventObject->myHandler5->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT5);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            else if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT6)
            {
                senderEventObject->myHandler5->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT6);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            else if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT1)
            {
                senderEventObject->myConnectionHandler->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT1);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            else if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT7)
            {
                senderEventObject->myConnectionHandler->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT7);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            else if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT2)
            {
                senderEventObject->myHandler4->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT2);
                Sleep(10);
            }
            else if (eventName == WFEVENTNAME_EVENT10)
            {
                senderEventObject->myHandler6->ProcessMessage(WFEVENTNAME_EVENT10);
                Sleep(10);
            }
        }

        senderEventObject->mySenderEvents.clear();
    }
}

int main()
{
    MessagingEventsNotifier obj;

    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
    {
        HANDLE handle1 = CreateEvent(NULL, 0, 0, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT10);
        SetEvent(handle1);
        Sleep(5);

        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            HANDLE handle2 = CreateEvent(NULL, 0, 0, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT3);
            SetEvent(handle2);
            Sleep(5);
        }

        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            HANDLE handle3 = CreateEvent(NULL, 0, 0, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT2);
            SetEvent(handle3);
            Sleep(5);
        }

        if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            HANDLE handle3 = CreateEvent(NULL, 0, 0, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT6);
            SetEvent(handle3);
            Sleep(5);
        }

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            HANDLE handle4 = CreateEvent(NULL, 0, 0, WFEVENTNAME_EVENT9);
            SetEvent(handle4);
            Sleep(5);
        }
    }

    HANDLE hEvent = CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, "SSSS");
    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE);
}
```

There are two threads:

- one will collect events
- another will process them sequentially.

My question is: whilst processing we might miss few events to collect; how to handle this scenario ?

I wanted to design the windows events mechanism and compression too.

Please help me in achieving this kind of mechanism.

Comment: What is your question? You already described the necessary steps: Collect the events for each time frame and then compress them. What do you need help with specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a list of events and the timestamps of when they were last processed.

When an you encounter an event, search for it in the list:

- if found, check if required time has passed,

  - if passed, process it and update its timestamp
  - else ignore
- if not found, add it to list with the timestamp and process it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, with your approach we might miss few events as we are ignoring.

Comment: And one more thing I want to process recently occurred event.

Comment: what do you intend to do with the processes occurring too frequently?

Comment: Hold the same series events until the event get processed. After that grab the latest occured event.